# My Lenovo laptop keeps muting my microphone when i press additional keys on my external keyboard

Tags: keyboard, lenovo-laptop, microphone

My PC is a Lenovo G50-80 with Windows 8. I bought a keyboard because i did not like the built-in one, and when i press keys that add or decrease sound, it mutes my microphone. I tried to do what other people did with similiar problems but none of them worked. I already tried: Disabling the “Allow applications to take exclusive control of this device” option, stopping processes that seemed suspicious and messing with some settings.
If you have a suggestion please let me know.

Comment: What have you tried? Just saying that you've tried what others tried doesn't give us enough information. Please use the EDIT button to add this information to your question to give us a better idea what the problem is, and to help us avoid having you do what you've already done.

Answer (score 0):

Having same problem with Lenovo laptop and Dell KB-522 keyboard.
The problem is connected with HID (Human Interface Device as suggested here https://www.dell.com/community/Windows-10/Dell-Kb522-Keyboard-on-Windows-10-1809-mute-sound-when-type/td-p/6240310)
Disabling this service help when you have problem with standard keys but then all multimedia will be unavailable.
Issue looks unresolved now so I treat this as best answer then for the major problem with mic muting.